# command output to file in crontab doesn't work

Tags: bash, command-line, cron, raspbian

I have a problem to show the output of a command on cli and redirect it also to a file on my Raspberry Pi 4 with Raspbian Buster.

I start `sudo crontab -e`.

These are my base statements:

```
0 */5 * * * sudo /home/pi/linux_scripts/block/blockips.sh > /var/log/blockips.log 2>&1 && sudo ufw status verbose > /var/log/ufw-status.log
```

The first part works but the second not because of permisson error on writing to `ufw-status.log`. Error message: `-bash: /var/log/blockips.log: Keine Berechtigung`

So I read several threads and tried this:

```
0 */5 * * * sudo /home/pi/linux_scripts/block/blockips.sh > /var/log/blockips.log 2>&1 && sudo ufw status verbose | sudo tee /var/log/ufw-status.log
```

That's not working. The file is still not changed after several days. But if I only try `sudo ufw status verbose | sudo tee /var/log/ufw-status.log` on command line (not crontab) it works.

Is the error in crontab or does the error depends on the first statement?

Can you help me?

Thanks.

Comment: Is `sudo` configured to allow you to run the `tee` command non-interactively, without asking for a password and with no TTY associated with the session? Has the cron daemon mailed any error messages to root's local inbox? (check with e.g. `sudo less /var/mail/root`)

Comment: What is the exact permissions error? Please don't generalise.

Comment: @telcoM: I didn't change anything in configs. `/var/mail/` is empty.

Comment: @roaima I edited my post.

Comment: Why is your error message prefixed by `-bash`? This indicates that you ran the command from a login shell, as far as I understand. Where do you see this error message? I'm curious about this as you say `/var/mail` is _empty_ (the cron daemon would ordinary mail the owner of the crontab, i.e. root, any output or error messages).

Answer (score 1):

You used `sudo crontab -e`, which edits the root crontab. As a result you don't need - and shouldn't use - `sudo` inside the `crontab` file itself because the commands are already being run as root.

Your crontab command can therefore be simplified to this

```
0 */5 * * * /home/pi/linux_scripts/block/blockips.sh > /var/log/blockips.log 2>&1 && ufw status verbose > /var/log/ufw-status.log
```

It's not good practice to run user scripts (i.e. those in a user's home directory) as root, but if you're the only user on the machine it's acceptable. (The reason is that your ordinary user can change the script to do anything whatsoever, and root will then obligingly run it for them.)

If you're getting errors the first place to look is in local email where `cron` sends its errors. You can use the `mail` or `mailx` command (as root, since it's from a root crontab), or *cheat* and just `less /var/mail/root` to see the raw mailfile.

Comment: I am the only user on my server, but I need to run as root because of ufw. Otherwise ufw is not found. `/var/mail/`is completly empty. No subdirectories or files in there. I simplified the statements now.

Comment: @user3646958 You don't need `sudo` inside the crontab because you are editing the root user's crontab, which means those commands would run as root anyway.

Comment: Yes, that's why I deleted `sudo` inside crontab.

Comment: But is it the solution for my problem? I will try.

Comment: @user3646958 you probably need to use the full path to the `ufw` command ex. `/usr/sbin/ufw` - it's found when you use `sudo` because sudo has its own `secure_path` that likely includes `/usr/sbin` (whereas cron's `PATH` likely doesn't)

Comment: I will try the absolute path, too. When I use `sudo crontab -e`, will ALL commands inside run as root? And what about the commands inside the scripts that I call inside crontab?

Comment: @user3646958 the root crontab will run all commands as root.

Comment: But why the root has no permission to write into a file?

Comment: Because of the `&&`, if the last command executed in the first script generates a non-zero return code, the second part of the command line will not be executed at all.

Comment: @user3646958 root does have permission. As [telcoM](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/258991/telcom) suggests are you confusing permissions with the action of `&&`, which can be understood like an `if` statement, i.e. `one && two` is equivalent to `if one; then two; fi`.

Comment: Thanks. I think that's the problem. I solved it by adding the second statement into my first script.

Comment: But now `sudo ufw status verbose > /var/log/ufw-status.log` doesn't work in command shell. Why I should not have permission? `-rw-r--r-- 1 root adm 1548706 Apr  5 14:44 /var/log/ufw-status.log`